# Need to build mobile UI for a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to begin building a mobile UI for one of my Rails apps.  A quick search brought me to the Titanium platform.  Any thoughts on using this?  Alternate suggestions are also welcome/appreciated.

In addition to my app rendering HTML, I am also able to easily create an API that will render JSON -- if that makes any difference regarding an answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at [jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)?

Comment: @PinnyM, thanks for the suggestion!  I'll add it to the list...

Answer (score 1):

No experience with Titanium, but I would start with a Web UI, optimized for mobile (small) devices. This would avoid you to build several (well, two : one Android and one iOS) different clients applications.

Many current web framework now help with building mobile web application (look at [Twitter Boostrap responsive features](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) for an example).

You may want a native app afterward, especially if :

1. You want to interact with the phone/device (get contacts, push notifications, use sensors)
2. The native look and feel is very important to your application

Even so, a lot of very good apps are actually "hybrids", mixing native widgets with webview (take a look at 37 signals [discussion](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3438-drawing-the-nativeweb-line-in-basecamp-for-iphone) about their new Basecamp iOS app).

In addition, if you are going the native way and are a Ruby developer (which I suppose), you may want to take a look at [Ruboto](http://ruboto.org/) (that allow to code applications for Android in Ruby) and [RubyMotion](http://www.rubymotion.com/) (same for iOS).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!  I've taken a look at Twitter Bootstrap but decided against it because some of my clients don't use 'modern' browsers - and it's a really big codebase.  It sounds like a fantastic option for a new site with no legacy CSS, though.  Also, I've seen the 37Signals discussion re: their 'hybrid' mobile interface.  It's pretty sweet - and I think I might be able to do just that using Titanium...?

Comment: No experience at all using Titanium. For the "modern browser" point, it is not that much a problem in the mobile space (no IE there, and browsers with auto update means generally a good support for the newer standards).

Comment: Good point, but if I were to use something like Twitter Bootstrap for the mobile portion, I'd likely use it for the non-mobile side also (which is where it becomes an issue for non-modern browsers.)  After looking some more at Titanium, it looks pretty good in terms of what I think I'm trying to accomplish (and I'll bet the folks at 37Signals used it - or something very similar to build their hybrid app.)  FYI, screencasts.org has a nice high-level cast on Titanium.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to further pursue using Titanium and will most likely be creating a hybrid app.  That said, both JQuery Mobile and Twitter Bootstrap also look nice!  Thanks everyone for looking.